# Does "present" mean "then" in this context?

Tags: meaning

> We believed war was shrinking to mere expeditionary affairs on the
> outskirts of our civilisation, a sort of frontier police business.
> Habits of tolerant intercourse, it seemed, were being strengthened
> every year that the peace of the Powers remained unbroken. There was
> in deed a mild armament race going on; mild by our **present** standards
> of equipment;
>
> - *The New World Order* by H.G.Wells (published in 1940)

The author talks about the time before the WW1. But this book is written in 1940.

Now by saying "present" does he talks about the time before 1914 or about 1940?

Comment: Did you look up the meaning of 'present' in a dictionary?

Comment: Wells is comparing armament races before 1914 to the "present day" of 1940.

Answer (score 2):

The New World Order was published in January 1940. In it, he proposed a framework of international arrangements that could guide the world towards world peace. Wells suggested that a world government would needed to ensure human rights.

Wells wrote the book after the outbreak of World War II. In the paragraph you quoted, he considers the situation regarding the development of weapons as it was prior to the outbreak of World War I, in 1914, and compares it to the situation in 1940 (the 'present' at the time of writing).

Answer (score -3):

Since the context suggests this was a diary entry (i.e. something that someone wrote during the time of the events), the author appears to be talking about the time before 1914.

Comment: _The New World Order_ is a non-fiction book written by H.G. Wells and was published in January 1940.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey this book is set before 1914.

Comment: @Lalala  It's a non-fiction book.  It's not "set" at any time.  He was talking about what people were thinking before 1914, but he's talking about it from the perspective of someone in 1940.